# How can the dimensions of a box be retrieved with LaTeX

Tags: tex-core, lengths, boxes

One can specify a box in LaTeX, using various methods for example:

```
 \newsavebox{\Abox}
 \savebox{\Abox}{\parbox{4cm}{\lorem}}
 \usebox{\Abox}
```

How can I retrieve the width, height and depth of the box. TeX has the primitives `\wd`, `\ht` and `\dp`. However in order for these to be used it is necessary to know the number of the box for example `\box13`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You really shouldn't be referring to boxes by number even with the plain format. For example,

```
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{Hello}
\showthe\wd\mybox
\bye
```

will work fine. Both `\newbox` and `\newsavebox` do a `\chardef` to assign the name you give as a number. So in LaTeX you can happily do

```
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{\parbox{4cm}{\lorem}}
\showthe\wd\mybox
```

and all will be fine.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. Out of curiosity, I see if I type \showthe\Abox I get the number 101, does LaTeX allocated from box100 onwards? Thanks for the tip though, I will not be using numbers even with the plain format :)

Comment: No, it's just that the kernel itself allocates a lot of things, both as boxes and as inserts (which need a box leaving free).

Answer (score 15):

I believe the canonical LaTeX way is this:

```
\newlength{\myhh}
\newlength{\mydd}
\newlength{\myww}
\settoheight{\myhh}{\usebox{\Abox}}
\settodepth{\mydd}{\usebox{\Abox}}
\settowidth{\myww}{\usebox{\Abox}}
```

Comment: Brent thanks. The question though asked how can the dimensions be retrieved i.e one or more of them might not be known. Is there a canonical way for this?

Comment: Yiannis, I don't fully understand the comment. If you have a TeX "thinh", the three lengths are always (I think) known. The lengths \myhh etc can be used as standard TeX lengths, I believe. What more do you want to do with them?