# Remove bullet and leading space before list item

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, enumitem

I have some nested lists that I'm trying to format.  I would like to remove the bullet and the leading space from the outer list while leaving the inner list unmodified.

Here is some sample code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection Titlte}

\begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt]
    %
    \item List item with bullet that I want gone
        \begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt]
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
        \end{itemize}
    %
    \item List item with bullet that I want gone
        \begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt]
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
        \end{itemize}
    %
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Below is an image that shows the output of the above code in the top half. The bottom half of the image shows what I would like my output to look like.  I've added the red and blue vertical lines to help illustrate the desired spacing. Note that the desired output removes both the bullet point and the leading space from the outer list.  It aligns the text of the outer list with the left side of the deleted bullet point.  The inner list remains completely unchanged.

I have attempted to use `enumitem` to set values for `leftmargin`, `labelindent`, and `labelsep`.  However, I can't figure out how to achieve the desired output.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Top is what I have, bottom is what I want]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you introduce `\bullet` for the outer list?

Comment: @TeXnician, I forgot to mention that in my original post.  I only added bullet to the outer list for illustrative purposes.  I know that I can easily remove the bullet by removing the $\bullet$ from the curly braces on the outer list.  However, simply removing the $\bullet$ from the outer list doesn't affect the spacing.  That's where I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{balditemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[balditemize]{label=, wide=\parindent, labelsep*=0pt, leftmargin=*, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection Title}

\begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt]
    %
    \item List item with bullet that I want gone
        \begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt]
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
        \end{itemize}
    %
    \item List item with bullet that I want gone
        \begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt]
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
        \end{itemize}
    %
\end{itemize}

\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection Title}

\begin{balditemize}
   \setlist[itemize, 1]{wide=\dimexpr\leftmargini-\fontdimen2\font, leftmargin=*, labelsep =5pt, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt}%
    \item List item with bullet that I want gone List item with bullet that I want gone List item with bullet that I want gone List item with bullet that I want gone
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets) Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets) Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets) Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
        \end{itemize}

    \item List item with bullet that I want gone
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
        \end{itemize}
    %
\end{balditemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have some code messed up in there, with the image and stuff.

Comment: Oh! yes. Some problem with my clipboard manager while  editing. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: Ahh, `setlist` with a level of 1, that's the magic I was looking for.  Anytime I attempted to alter the spacing on the outer list I also affected the spacing on the inner list.  After reading the documentation on `setlist` it appears to be just what I need.

Comment: I have a question about the `22pt` value that you selected for `wide`.  Where did you get this number from?  I was trying to avoid magic numbers so that the outer list without the bullet would align with other lists in my document.

Comment: By trial and error. I first tried with intrinsic lengths (such as  \labelselsep or \labelwidth), but there remained a small difference, probably in relation with the bullet width, so I ended up in adjusting the value of `wide=`.

Comment: @James: Finally, I've found a more automatic way, subtracting from `leftmargin` the average value of interword space (`\fontdimen2`).

Comment: Much of this is new to me, so I appreciate you taking the time to explore and answer my question.  From my reading, it appears that `\dimexpr` permits arithmetic computations on the values provided (subtraction in your solution).  I've been using the `calc` package in my main document, and it appears to provide the same functionality as `\dimexpr`.  After testing, `\dimexpr` doesn't appear to cause any conflicts with the `calc` package so leaving it in causes no harm.

Comment: How did you come up with a `labelsep` value of 5pt?  Is that simply the default width between the bullet and the text?  If so, is that value accessibly via a variable for a completely automated solution with no magic numbers?

Comment: It can cause no harm indeed , as it is a new (well, not so new now) primitive of ε-tex, along with `\numexpr` and `\glueexpr`.

Comment: I think it's indeed the default. Didn't check, though.

Comment: @Bernard, I really like this solution, but I encountered issues as soon as I began incorporating it into my document.  I have a global `\raggedright` setting that is applied immediately before `\begin{document}`.  With `\raggedright` set, the indentation of the bald list somehow reverts all the way back to the left margin.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What about trying `\RaggedRight`?

Comment: `\RaggedRight` produces the same issue.  The indentation for the bald list is lost.

Comment: I've just tested. It seems `\raggedright` kills `\parindent`Here's a solution: replace `wide=\parindent` with `wide=\dimexpr 20pt-\labelsep` (20pt is the default for \parindent)

Comment: AMAZING ... @Bernard you are truly a TEX master!  Not only does that modification work in the example above, but it also works in a newenvironment that I created to indent a complete subsection.  Adding this modification to your answer above makes it a perfect solution for my desired format.  Thank you so much for sharing your expertise.

Answer (score 4):

You might want a more automatic approach, but here is an ad-hoc solution:

You could use `\item[]` combined with leftmargin. By inspecting the values, the default leftmargin seem to be `25pt`, and the width of the `\bullet` seem to be `5pt` and the spacing between the bullet and the text also `5pt`. Thus the new leftmargin should be `25pt - 10pt=15pt`. Also we have to add `5pt` to the "inner" left margin (`5pt+25pt=30pt`) to make up for the distance removed between the bullet and the item: and it actually works as expected:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection Title}
\begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt]
    %
    \item List item with bullet that I want gone (below)
        \begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt]
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
        \end{itemize}
    %
    \item List item with bullet that I want gone (below)
        \begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt]
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
        \end{itemize}
    %
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin=15pt]
    %
    \item[] List item with bullet that I want gone
        \begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin=30pt]
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
        \end{itemize}
    %
    \item[] List item with bullet that I want gone
        \begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin=30pt]
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
            \item Inner list item (I want to keep these bullets)
        \end{itemize}
    %
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Where did you find the default values for `leftmargin`, and `bullet`?  I wasn't sure where to find this information.

Comment: Inside the `item` environment, I just did `\the\leftmargin`. Furthermore I used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3168/85834) to get the width of the bullet point :)

Comment: If I use a different character for the bullet point, will that width change?  For example, if I use `label={}`on the outer list will that 5pt decrease?  If so, is there a way to automatically determine the width of the bullet character?